# Thread was being aborted exception thrown when opening workbook in a new Interop Excel process

Tags: c#, vsto, excel-interop

I have an excel com add in that performs some operations on an excel workbook. The idea is that when a default excel file is opened, an exposed function on the com add in (OpenFile) will be called from vba within this workbook. At this point, the add in will open a new excel process and open the user workbook there. It works most of the time, but occasionally it throws the following exception at the marked line:

INFO , 05:31:12: Message: Thread was being aborted.
INFO , 05:31:12: Inner Exception:
INFO , 05:31:12: Source: mscorlib
INFO , 05:31:12: HResult: -2146233040
INFO , 05:31:12: Target site: Void ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32, IntPtr)
INFO , 05:31:12: Stack Trace:    at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
at System.Dynamic.ComRuntimeHelpers.CheckThrowException(Int32 hresult, ExcepInfo& excepInfo, UInt32 argErr, String message)
at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , ComObject , String , Boolean )
at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute3[T0,T1,T2,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid3[T0,T1,T2](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
at VbaApi.AddInApi.OpenFile(String path, Boolean fromVba)

When it fails, the newly created process crashes and closes. It appears to be thrown at completely random locations in the RealOpen function so it is not something specific failing within the function. Sometimes it is not thrown at all and the workbook opens in the new process and functions fine.

Below is the code that is producing the exception:

```
public void OpenFile(string path, bool fromVba)
        {
            if (fromVba)
            {
                // if called from vba, create a new application object and make visible
                Excel.Application singleApp = new Excel.Application();

                // show new application
                singleApp.Visible = true;
                     
                // Get process id
                int processId = ExcelFunctions.GetExcelProcessId(singleApp);

                // give new app focus
                ExcelFunctions.BringMainWindowToFront(processId);

                // get ComAddIn in new application instance
                COMAddIn addIn = singleApp.COMAddIns.Item(ExcelFunctions.GetVersion(singleApp.Version));
                
                // connect it
                addIn.Connect = true;
                
                // automation object
                dynamic automationObject = addIn.Object;

                try
                {
                    // call open file in new instance                                        
                    automationObject.OpenFile(path, false); // Exception is thrown here
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    LoggerFactory.Logger.Debug(e.StackTrace);
                }
                // close original application if no other workbooks open
                ExcelFunctions.CloseSession(application);              
            }
            else
            {
                RealOpen(path);                
            }
        }

        private void RealOpen(string path)
        {
            try
            {
                OnRealOpen?.Invoke(path);
                if (path.StartsWith("Cannot decode:"))
                {
                    string error = "Error during download.";
                    LoggerFactory.Logger.Error(error);
                    AlertUser();
                    return;
                }

                dynamic WinHttpReq = VBAFunctions.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                WinHttpReq.Open("GET", path, false);
                WinHttpReq.Send();

                string FileName = WinHttpReq.GetResponseHeader("Content-Disposition");
                if (FileName == null)
                {
                    AlertUser();
                    return;
                }
                FileName = FileName.Substring(10);
                FileName = FileName.Substring(0, FileName.Length - 1);

                // check if file is already open on this machine           
                if (ExcelFunctions.CheckIfWorkbookOpen(FileName))
                    return;

                SavePath = Path.GetTempPath() + FileName;
                byte[] caseTemplateWithoutData = WinHttpReq.ResponseBody;

                if (WinHttpReq.Status == 200)
                {
                    using (var fs = new FileStream(SavePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                    {
                        fs.Write(caseTemplateWithoutData, 0, caseTemplateWithoutData.Length);
                    }
                    
                    GetMetaData("http://test.com", SavePath);
                }
                else
                {
                    string error = "Cannot open, download file error.";
                    LoggerFactory.Logger.Error(error + " http status: " + WinHttpReq.Status + " ResponseText: " + WinHttpReq.ResponseText);
                    AlertUser();
                    return;
                }
                SaveDisabled?.Invoke();

                // Closing current workbook, and opens case.
                ReOpenExcel?.Invoke(SavePath); // It never reaches this point when it fails

                // Set focus to ribbon tab.       
                ActivateTab();
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                LoggerFactory.Logger.Error($"RealOpen - Error: { ee.Message }.");
            }
        }
```

Any guidance on what the issue could be would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Rebuild app with Debug configuration instead of Release to have line numbers in exception stacktrace. Identify the failing call using row number in code snippet above (and tell us which line was that).

Comment: @cly Thanks for the response. That is part of my problem. I can not seem to reproduce the issue in a dev environment. Only with deployed application.  But the line that throws the exception is: 
                    automationObject.OpenFile(path, false); // Exception is thrown here 
at least this is where it is being caught, in OpenFile, it is always at different locations, like it is a timing issue or race condition.

Comment: Have a look at the executing machine's event log (eventvwr.exe, system and application logs). Maybe some related info is hidden there.

Answer (score 0):

Do not create a new instance of the `Excel.Application` object. Also keep in mind that COM objects have thread affinity, so if you create a new COM object on a secondary thread, release it (and all its child objects) using `Marshal.ReleaseComObject()`.